# WORDPRESS 403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami, pagespeed, permission-denied

i have a problem with my website. I can't access to wp admin. if i click wp admin, it will redirect to

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource,

i already tried resetting the permission, but still nothing happened.

i have open support on Github issue bitnami, but still no reply for 3 days.

Here is the report log after i run bndiagnostic tool :

```
>  ? Apache: Found possible issues
    ? WordPress: Found possible issues
    ✓ resources: No issues found
    ✓ mysql: No issues found
    ✓ php: No issues found


> Found recent Pagespeed related error messages in the Apache error log:

>[Mon Jul 11 06:53:00.801224 2022] [pagespeed:error] [pid 8475:tid 140283220059904] [mod_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0 @8475] /opt/bitnami/apache2/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/shm_metadata_cache/snapshot/pagespeed_default_shm/metadata_cache/1/64/4452/128/59,.tempGmnDMS:0: opening temp file: Permission denied

>We suggest disabling pagespeed and check if that improves the behavior. Please check the following guide to disable Pagespeed:

>https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/administration/use-pagespeed/#disable-pagespeed

>Found recent WordPress plugin related error messages in the Apache error log.Please check the following guide to deactivate plugins:

>https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/deactivate/
```

how to deactivate pagespeed step by step? i have zero knowledge about coding. i'm using SSH to login the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

403 forbidden could be caused by:

1. a Wordpress plugin: try disabling all wp plugins on your website by renaming plugins folder
2. damaged .htaccess: inspect the file or upload a brand new .htaccess file
3. wrong permission on folder (wp-admin in this case)

In all these cases I suggest using an FTP file manager like Filezilla

Comment: If the htaccess was damaged, you'd receive a 500 internal server error, not a 403

Comment: 1) how to repair the .htaccess to new one using SSH?

Comment: you can use Putty https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

Example of command to upload a file from your computer to your server:

c:\pscp c:\yourfolder\path\to\a\file.txt user@remote:\home\user\some\path

Comment: Since SCP is based on SSH, you may also find success with WinSCP, and it's much more intuitive than Putty.

Comment: how about the permisson folder? what command need to write?

Comment: chmod 755 wp-admin

Comment: this one? sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

Comment: sudo find /opt/bitnami/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

or 

sudo find /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-admin -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Comment: still no luck.. i can't follow that command line because it appears only No such directory.. but on my site, it can be access with 'sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs

Comment: better using a visual interface for checking files.
Read this guide: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress-production-ready/administration/upload-files/

Comment: already login to winscp and here my folder.. https://imgur.com/XYTugfL

Comment: right click on the folder > Properties 
wp-admin should be 755

Comment: yes, same https://imgur.com/5NdNRBt but still can't access the wp-admin area :(

Comment: Check .htacces, or disable plugins

Comment: i have tried the two ways still no luck.. no problem with .htaccess even i change to new one.. also when deactivate the plugin, still can't access to the wp-admin panel

Comment: uhm... do you have an error log? Something like php_errorlog in you wp root folder

Comment: i have but i don't know how to share here because the file is 162mb

Comment: Just copy the most recent logs here

Comment: [[Sun Jul 10 00:00:04.335402 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1202:tid 140263230137664] AH00489: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1i configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 10 00:00:04.335415 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1202:tid 140263230137664] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -D DISABLE_BANNER'
[Sun Jul 10 00:00:45.032736 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 23317:tid 140261619398400] [client 2.56.57.132:53221] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /